# Why a feature is still required though declared as optional in AndroidManifest?

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

My app collects diagnostic data from the phone. Naturally, it needs permissions like `android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` to access the hardware. Android consequently assumes that `android.hardware.WIFI` feature is required. Though that would be indeed a valid guess in most cases, in my case the Wi-Fi is not really required for the normal operation. The app checks for the actually present modules, and if Wi-Fi was not there it would just skip to the next module.

Following the documentation, I declared

```
   <uses-feature android:required="false" android:name="android.hardware.WIFI"/>
```

in my AndroidManifest. Unfortunately, it does not work as expected! The feature is still listed as required.

Here is the exempt from `aapt` inspection. Though my declaration had an initial effect, it was immediately overridden by the permission:

```
    uses-feature-not-required: name='android.hardware.WIFI'
    uses-feature: name='android.hardware.wifi'
    uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.wifi' reason='requested android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE permission'
```

Does anyone know how to make the feature be optional? Really appreciate your help, guys!

---

## UPDATE: SOLUTION

Thanks CommonsWare for the answer, the problem was indeed the upper case in the my declaration (facepalm).

Bad:

```
   <uses-feature android:required="false" android:name="android.hardware.WIFI"/>
```

Good:

```
   <uses-feature android:required="false" android:name="android.hardware.wifi"/>
```

With the lower case everything works as documented.

*Now, the most frustrating: how did I end up with the uppercase there? - I simply copied it from the Google Play listing. So, guys, be cautious when checking there. What you normally do? - You build the APK, you upload it to Google Play, you check the version/permissions/features - NOPE, that's the trap!  You see it in upper case there. Don't fall for it :)*

Comment: is this even really an issue? What I mean by that are there any devices that dont have WiFi?

Comment: Wi-Fi is just one of many. The app probes all sorts of modules, e.g. GPS, Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, NFC, Keypad, etc, etc. Basically, every possible HW. There are few, if any, devices that have *all* of that on board. Having every permission drag an associated feature narrows the device filter so much that I get "Supported: 0 devices" in Play Store. *That's* the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android, like many operating systems, is case-sensitive. Try:

```
<uses-feature android:required="false" android:name="android.hardware.wifi"/>
```